# save class state of multiple divs in cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle, toggleclass

I have this toggleClass function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("button#playersize").click(function(){
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("small large");
        $(".divone").toggleClass("small large");
        $(".divtwo").toggleClass("small large");
    });
});
```

This changes the classes of the divs between "small" and "large" onclick button.

I would like to save the class of the divs (#wrapper, .divone, .divtwo) to a cookie.
And on reload, the class should be the saved one.

How do I manage this?

I have the jquery cookie plugin embedded already.
My code is probably a bit redundant, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // replace the classes from the cookies
    // example if you want to check the cookie first
    if ($.cookie('class_wrapper').length > 0) {
        $("#wrapper").attr('class', $.cookie('class_wrapper'));
    } else {
        $("#wrapper").attr('class', 'small');
    }
    $(".divone").attr('class', $.cookie('class_divone'));
    $(".divtwo").attr('class', $.cookie('class_divtwo'));
    // bind the click event 
    $("button#playersize").click(function(){
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("small large");
        $(".divone").toggleClass("small large");
        $(".divtwo").toggleClass("small large");
        // replace the cookie values
        $.cookie('class_wrapper', $("#wrapper").attr('class'));
        $.cookie('class_divone', $(".divone").attr('class'));
        $.cookie('class_divtwo', $(".divtwo").attr('class'));  
    });
});
```

*Caveat*: not tested yet

Comment: Thank you very much! What if the divs need the class "small" by default, when nothing is saved in the cookie? The class should only be small OR large.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show an example you can adapt for the other cases. Yet, you should probably define the default behavior in your HTML generation (PHP, ASP or else)

Comment: it looks pretty good, but gives me the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: len is not defined" do you know where the problem is?

Comment: sorry, I'm mixing up languages, you have to use `.length`. I edited my code

Comment: thank you so far, seem to work in chrome and firefox, but in safari and IE it looks like there is a conflict with other jQuery stuff. My jquery-ui sortable for example is no more working. Any idea?

Comment: we can't help you more without seeing more code. Have a look at some debug to see if the console raise any error. If it still doesn't work, you'd better ask a new question giving as much information as you can.

Comment: Firebug gives me: "$.cookie("class_wrapper") is null" as a error.