# Storing toggleClass state using js-cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I saw similar code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150555/save-class-state-of-multiple-divs-in-cookie) but the solution provided is more complicated than what I'm looking for. If someone could simplify that, that would be great.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#togglecbox").click(function() {
    $(".cbox").toggleClass("cbox2");
    $(".wrapper2").toggleClass("wrapper3");
    $(".container>.control-bar").toggleClass("contentfloat");
  });
});
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('cbox', $('.cbox').hasClass('cbox2'))`

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction thank you!